# Combine two tables on 4 similar columns and keep the unique columns

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have two tables, one table has columns

"DATE","PRODUCT","SUBPRODUCT","ACTUALS","RANDOM1"

The 2nd table has

"DATE,"PRODUCT","SUBPRODUCT","ACTUALS","RANDOM2"

Date, product, subproduct, actuals are the same values for both tables, and random1 and random 2 are unique values.

I want the final table to be

"DATE","PRODUCT","SUBPRODUCT","ACTUALS","RANDOM1","RANDOM2"

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Hey, I'm a complete newbie in SQL, i've updated the above

Answer (score 1):

A simple way in standard SQL uses `join` with the `using` clause:

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     using (col1, col2, col3, col4) ;
```

SQL Server doesn't support the `using` clause, so alas, you need to list columns.  A typical method is:

```
select t1.*, t2.random2
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.product = t2.product and
        t1.subproduct = t2.subproduct and
        t1.actuals = t2.actuals;
```

Note:  This only returns rows that match between both tables.  If you want all rows, you can use a `full join` and tweak the `select`.

Comment: When I tried this, it says there is a "syntax error near using"

Comment: @chriswang123 .  . . This is standard SQL and supported by many databases.  Your question has no other indication of the database you are using.

Comment: Oh, okay I understand now. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables using where clause like below

```
select t1.DATE, t1.PRODUCT, t1.SUBPRODUCT, t1.ACTUALS, t1.RANDOM1, t2.RANDOM2
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.DATE = t2.DATE and t1.PRODUCT = t2.PRODUCT and t1.SUBPRODUCT = t2.SUBPRODUCT and t1.ACTUALS = t2.ACTUALS
```

It will return data like this

[image]